# Debounce a vuejs method with Lodash `_this2.getPoeples is not a function`

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I try to make a debounce with lodash on a method.

My input :

```
<el-input
    placeholder="Search poeples"
    suffix-icon="el-icon-search"
    @input="debounceGetPoeples"
    v-model="keywords">
</el-input>
```

My debounce in methods:

```
debounceGetPoeples: debounce(() => {
        console.log('Debounce ok');
        this.getPoeples();
      }, 500),
```

The debounce is working but I get an error when I call another method in my view component `_this2.getPoeples is not a function`

I try to do a normal function for my debounce but when I do it, it is ignored

```
debounceGetAnimals() {
    return debounce(() => {
      console.log('debounce ok');
      this.getPoeples();
    }, 300)
  }
```

How can I make my debounce work and call another method inside?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had that too. I don't now why the arrow notation does not work... I guess it has something to do with the timeout used by lodash.

Try:

```
debounceGetAnimals() {
   var that = this;
   return debounce(() => {
      console.log('debounce ok');
      that.getPoeples();
   }, 300)
}
```

this solutions works for me.
The other way it works for me, and here the "this" works is writing the call in classic way:

```
debounceGetAnimals:debounce(
   function() {
        console.log('debounce ok');
       this.getPoeples();
    }, 300)
```